# Is it possible to remove the timezone from a cal event?

Tags: events, datepicker, timezone, fullcalendar

im using fullcalendar and i would like to remove the timezone from the calEvent.start. How can i do this? 
i thought something like this:

```
$("#startstatus").val(calEvent.start)({ startFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

instead of:

```
$("#startstatus").val(calEvent.start),
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: that i get this output:Mon Feb 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West-Europa (standaardtijd)) instead i would like to get it like this: 2014-03-24

Comment: Are you trying to format the date to display it? Or are you trying to make your calendar ignore the timezone? which version of fullcalendar are you using? 1.6/2?